# Extracting numbers from a string in java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I have a string like this `3x^2` I want to extract the first and the second number and store them in an array. and if they didn't exist they should be considered as `1`.

EDIT :
For example in string `x` the first and the second number are `1`
or in string `3x` the second number is 1. I think it should be clear now.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question by giving a more general expression which you want to process and extract?

Comment: You are way too vague. what do you mean? numbers separated by a separator, like "1-558-3" or numbers without any separator, like "15583"?
if it's the second case, how is the application to know the first number is 1 and not 15, 155, ... ?

Comment: @Stultuske@Tim Biegeleisen see my updated post.

Comment: in "3x" the second number is 1 ... there is no 1 in that String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get digits with the Regex:

```
String str = "3x^2";
String pattern = "(\\d+)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Find with `Matcher` all numbers and add them to the `ArrayList`. Don't forget to convert them to `int`, because `m.group()` returns the `String`.

```
while (m.find()) {
   numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
}
```

And if your formula doesn't contain the second number, add there your desired default item.

```
if (numbers.size<2) {
   numbers.add(1);
}
```

Finally print it out with:

```
for (int i: numbers) {
   System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

And the output for `3x^2` is `3 2`.

And for the `8x` it is `8 1`.

Answer (score 1):

if the numbers are allways separated by x^, just split the string using this separator

```
String[] splitted = "3x^2".split("x\\^");
```